# What kind of license does xConnect require?

Tags: xconnect, licensing

I'm trying to price out costs for a Sitecore 9 upgrade for some clients. For customers on 8.x that are running a single Sitecore application in a hybrid CM and Processing role, they need only one license for that instance. When we upgrade to Sitecore 9, however, xConnect will be a separate application with a separate license.

I assume, it's not acceptable to use the same license for CM and xConnect, even if they're running on the same server. Does xConnect require another standard Sitecore production license, with the same pricing model? Or, is there a different license for xConnect with a different pricing model? This would be for perpetual licenses, not consumption.

I know this can be specific to the customer, but I think the general licensing model around xConnect is good knowledge for the community to have. Sitecore's documentation has not been updated to cover licensing for Sitecore 9 yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best answer is "ask your Sitecore Sales rep". With that said, I did ask the sales team while at Sitecore Symposium and they said it wouldn't require any additional licences outside of what Sitecore 8 xDB support required.

Again, I would ask your sales rep as they may give you a different answer as it will very by each customer.

Answer (score 5):

xConnect is part of Sitecore's xDB offering, so normal xDB license (with module *Sitecore.xDB.Base*) is enough.